# GoDaddy does not show newly added file

Tags: hosting, cpanel, godaddy-api

I uploaded a new .php file to GoDaddy via Cpanel. It works on my local, but when I try to run it on live, it shows 404 on console. Seems like it cannot see the new file.
Is there some sort of latency on Godaddy servers like uploaded files appear X hours later or something? Or what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope Cpannel is pretty close to instant. Be sure your .php file is named index.php and is in a folder that has the desired url. (This may not be what’s preventing you from seeing the file, just a common issue I’ve seen that’s on the quick check list.) do not use capital letters or spaces when naming your index file.

You also get hosting support over the phone with godaddy. This is there number. +1-480-463-8389.

But feel free to use their url to find their support number.